# Default pure virtual destructor

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11, we are able to declare a destructor to be auto generated:

```
struct X {
  virtual ~X() = default;
};
```

Also, we can declare a destructor to be pure virtual:

```
struct X {
  virtual ~X() = 0;
};
```

My question is: how to declare the destructor to be *both* auto generated *and* pure virtual?  Looks like the following syntax is not correct:

```
struct X {
  virtual ~X() = 0 = default;
};
```

Neither is this one:

```
struct X {
  virtual ~X() = 0, default;
};
```

Nor this one:

```
struct X {
  virtual ~X() = 0 default;
};
```

EDIT:
Some clarification on the purpose of the question.  Basically I want an *empty* class to be non-instantiable base class, but derived class is instantiable, then the class must have a pure virtual destructor. But on the other hand, I don't want to provide the definition in a .cpp file.  So I need some sort of mechanism equivalent to `default`.  I wonder if anyone has an idea to solve the problem.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In order to define a pure virtual method, you need a separate definition from the declaration.

Therefore:

```
struct X {
    virtual ~X() = 0;
};

X::~X() = default;
```

Comment: Here's a [link to an Ideaone example](http://ideone.com/Y4iPA) that successfully compiles.

Comment: darn, you beat me to it while I was getting my copy of effective C++ (where this is shown using the old syntax)

Comment: This answer is incorrect! You still need to put the line `X::~X() = default; ` into the .cpp file, otherwise there will be `multiple definition` linking error.

Comment: @icando unless you write `inline`; That's not implied when `default` is it?

Comment: @Dave: it is not, but all methods defined within the class scope are `inline` by default so it is easy to get confused.

Comment: And here is an [updated ideaone example](http://ideone.com/vjnxzS) based on the @nicol-bolas code. I also edited the answer, but StackOverflow warns me `This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed`.

Comment: @vinipsmaker: Your edit was actually rejected, though it's borderline here. I prefer not to put the `inline` in this answer, as it is necessary in a header file but useless in a source file. In the end, therefore, I think this is an orthogonal issue (since here `X::~X` could be defined in either), and it might actually confuse the reader into thinking `inline` is always mandatory when defining pure virtual methods, which is not the case obviously.

Comment: @MatthieuM. no problem. And I agree it is an orthogonal problem. All discussion prior to my comment is enough for any reader.

Comment: It seems like a silly semantic issue that a definition has to be separated from its declaration simply to use these 2 together.

Comment: @void.pointer: I would even go so far as a silly *syntactic* issue! :)

Comment: That would also be an appropriate complaint! Good answer!

Comment: I didn't know that delete/default keyword could be used inside cpp file as well.

Comment: @nurabha: Then I am glad to have provided you with this nugget of information :)

Comment: Does anyone know _why_ C++ doesn't generate a default implementation for pure virtual destructors, and doesn't let you use the `default` keyword either ?