# Proper placement for the default pure virtual destructor in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-destructor

I have an interface class but I want all derived classes to implement the virtual destructor:

```
// Interface.h
class Interface {
    virtual ~Interface() = 0;
};

Interface::~Interface() = default;
```

The problem is that in this case I have a linker error because of duplicated symbols.

I can place the definition in `.cpp` file but I'd like to know if there is more elegant solution?

Comment: Maybe `inline Interface::~Interface() = default;`?

Comment: function(destructor) cant be abstract and have implementation (default) at the same time.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur, yes it can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777606/c11-interface-pure-virtual-destructor

Comment: Why make the destructor pure virtual ? It doesn't add anything. Destructors already have to be implemented (or defaulted) for all classes.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker it's a usual trick to make the class abstract when it doesn't have any member function to make pure virtual.

Comment: @Quentin : I get that, but the OP specifically states it's done because he wants "derived classes to implement the virtual destructor".

Comment: @SanderDeDycker fair enough -- that, I don't know.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur, from (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor): A **destructor may be declared pure virtual**, for example in a base class which needs to be made abstract, but has no other suitable functions that could be declared pure virtual. **Such destructor must have a definition**,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add inline before. According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor this syntax is OK:

```
decl-specifier-seq(optional) ~ class_name () = default;

decl-specifier-seq  -   friend, inline, virtual, or nothing (no return type)
```