# How to get rid of these warnings?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
 #include "Pizza.h"

int main() {

 iFood* food;

food = new Pizza(14.0, 8);

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     food->consume();
 food->display();
 std::cout << std::endl;

 delete food;

 food = new DeluxePizza(12.0, 6, "mushrooms, peppers");

 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     food->consume();
 food->display();
 std::cout << std::endl;

 delete food;
 }
```

This is my main.cpp
when I run this code, it shows the warning that delete called on iFood that is abstract but has non-virtual destructor.

Comment: #include<iostream>
class iFood{
public:
virtual void consume()=0;
virtual void display() const=0;
};

Comment: You shouldn't be using `new` here in the first place. C++ is not Java, don't try to blindly copy things you learned there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the destructor `virtual` in `iFood`.

See [Why do we need a pure virtual destructor in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219607/why-do-we-need-a-pure-virtual-destructor-in-c) to understand why.