# Inheritance from class with pure abstract destructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

If a parent class has a pure virtual destructor, how can I proper inherit from it? I have a header file (generated by IBM Rational Rose) which looks like this:

```
class MyClass{
protected:
  inline MyClass() {};
  MyClass(const MyClass&);
  MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&);
public:
  inline virtual ~MyClass() = 0;
  virtual void someMethod() = 0;
};
```

Now I want to implement this pure-abstract class - i.e.

```
class MyClassImpl : public MyClass {
public:
  MyClassImpl(){}
  virtual void someMethod() {}
};

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
  MyClassImpl impl;
  return 0;
}
```

But whatever I try (i.e. define a destructor in MyClassImpl; virtual/non-virtual), I keep getting the error message: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall MyClass::~MyClass(void)" (??1MyClass@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall MyClassImpl::~MyClassImpl(void)" (??1MyClassImpl@@UAE@XZ)`.

Is there any way to implement `MyClassImpl` without changes to `MyClass`?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Looks like msvc but just to confirm.

Comment: You cannot destroy an instance of a class that has no destructor. You could only ever create one dynamically and then leak it.

Comment: Since 'MyClass::~MyClass( void )' cannot be resolved. Define that method in the header file or in a separate file like @MinorThreat posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must define the destructor even if it is pure virtual (uniquely).

Add

```
MyClass::~MyClass() {}
```

in exactly one .CPP file.

(See for example http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor under "Pure virtual destructors". Also [Why do we need a pure virtual destructor in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219607/why-do-we-need-a-pure-virtual-destructor-in-c).)

Comment: Is this possible with regular member functions?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Yes. You can define any pure virtual function, but you can only invoke it via a non-virtual call, e.g. `base::foo()`.

Answer (score 2):

Rather declare your `virtual` destructor like this, with a body:

```
inline virtual ~MyClass() {};
inline virtual ~MyClass() = default; // C++11
```

It has to be implemented (not just declared), otherwise, there will be no way to destruct `MyClass` and its derived classes (your declaration disables default-generated destructor, but does not provide substituting implementation).

Note that `virtual` member function can still have an implementation, so you can have:

```
inline virtual ~MyClass() = 0;
```

and

```
virtual MyClass::~MyClass() {}; // defined in .h file because of inline
```

Comment: `= 0;` as in OP's code, forces the derived class to override the destructor. Presumably this is intentional (there's no other reason why someone would do this) .  Your first suggestion changes the behaviour.  (Also, on your first two lines `inline` is redundant , providing the body inline implies `inline`)

Answer (score 2):

C++ compiler adds some implicit autogenerated code during compilation.

```
class MyClassImpl : public MyClass {
public:
  MyClassImpl(){}
  virtual void someMethod() {}

  // Begin autogenerated code
  virtual ~MyClassImpl() {
    MyClass::~MyClass(); // <- This will break because your parent class
                         // lacks any destructor body and linker will             
                         // report the missing symbol.
  }
  // End autogenerated code

};
```

Luckily for you, you can define destructor body in any cpp file without touching files generated by Rational Rose. For example, you can add this line near your `main()` function.

```
MyClass::~MyClass(){} // Empty destructor
```

Comment: this maybe explain the problem but it doesn't say any solution