# Can a compiler inline a virtual function if I use a pointer in a clear situation?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, virtual, inline

I've already read [Are inline virtual functions really a non-sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733737/are-inline-virtual-functions-really-a-non-sense/). But I still have some doubts and found no answer there.

They say that *if situation isn't ambiguous, compiler should inline the virtual function*.

However:

> This can happen only when the compiler has an actual object rather than a pointer or reference to an object.

So what if I have a `B` class derived from an `A` one (which contains a `virtual void doSth()` function) and I use the `B*` pointer, not the `A*`:

```
B* b = new B;

b->doSth();
```

1. Suppose that the `B` hasn't any child classes. It's rather obvious (on the compile time) what function should be called. So it's possible to be inlined. Is it in fact?
2. Suppose that the `B` has some child classes but these classes haven't its own `doSth()` function. So compiler should "know" that the only function to call is `B::doSth()`. I guess it doesn't inline though?

Comment: I would bet that it depends on the compiler and you just have to look at the generated assembly to find out.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [inline virtual function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130226/inline-virtual-function)

Comment: Actually this is rather question about compiler.
David, GCC.

Comment: And its version is `4.4.1`. Do you think it's smart enough to inline in 1. and 2. situation?

Comment: The real question is why allocate `B` on the heap if even the compiler can detect the pointers static type? Why can't the programmer do that as well?

Comment: I'm not sure. Are talking about use `::` with derived class name?

If yes, because of a comfort. If I have a lot of such calls and I'll modify operations with `b` before them I want compiler to detect it automatically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether `B` has any derived classes. In that situation `b` points to a `B` object so the compiler can inline the call.

And surely any decent modern compiler can and will do that in your situation. If you don't use pointers it becomes a whole lot easier. It's not really an "optimization" then. The fact that you can omit a virtual call then becomes obvious by only looking at the AST node at the left side of the `.`-operator. But if you use pointers, you need to track the dynamic type of the pointee. But modern compilers are capable of that.

EDIT: Some experiment is in order.

```
// main1.cpp
struct A {
  virtual void f();
};

struct B : A { 
  virtual void f();
};

void g() {
  A *a = new A;
  a->f();

  a = new B;
  a->f();
}

// clang -O2 -S -emit-llvm -o - main1.cpp | c++filt
// ...
define void @g()() {
  %1 = tail call noalias i8* @operator new(unsigned int)(i32 4)
  %2 = bitcast i8* %1 to %struct.A*
  %3 = bitcast i8* %1 to i32 (...)***
  store i32 (...)** bitcast (i8** getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8*]* @vtable for A, i32 0, i32 2) to i32 (...)**), i32 (...)*** %3, align 4
  tail call void @A::f()(%struct.A* %2)
  %4 = tail call noalias i8* @operator new(unsigned int)(i32 4)
  %5 = bitcast i8* %4 to i32 (...)***
  store i32 (...)** bitcast (i8** getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8*]* @vtable for B, i32 0, i32 2) to i32 (...)**), i32 (...)*** %5, align 4
  %tmp = bitcast i8* %4 to %struct.B*
  tail call void @B::f()(%struct.B* %tmp)
  ret void
}
// ...
```

As can be seen, clang does direct calls to `f`, both when `a` points to a `A` and when it points to a `B`. GCC does that too.

Comment: What if B has a child class that's not visible from the current source file? Are you saying the compiler will track the assignment and "know" that `b` contains an actual `B*` and not a child?

Comment: Mark: that's exactly what he's saying.

Comment: Thank you. So it seems GCC is pretty inteligent.

Comment: @Johannes, thanks for going to the trouble. Looks like I have to stop underestimating the capabilities of modern compilers; this isn't the first time I've been surprised.

Comment: @Mark: Attempting to infer the static type of a pointed-to value is fairly simple using [data-flow analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis), a technique which is used for many optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual member function can be inlined when the vtable is not dereferenced for the call. This can be accomplished by making an explicitly scoped call to the member function.

```
class A
{
protected:

    int     a;
public:
    inline virtual void Func()
    {
        a = 0;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    inline virtual void Func()
    {
        a = 1;
    }
};

B   *obj = new B();

obj->Func();    //  Calls B::Func() through vtable;
obj->A::Func(); //  Inlines calls to A::Func();
obj->B::Func(); //  Inlines calls to B::Func();
```

Comment: True. But I'm also wondering if compiler is smart enough to not look to vtable if it "sees" `obj->Func();`.