# what to do with the destructors in an interface

Tags: c++, oop, interface, destructor

When I write interface classes in C++, I choose either of the following 2 options

```
class Interface
{
public:
   virtual R1 f1(p11, p12 , ...) = 0;
   ...
   virtual Rn fn(pn1, pn2 , ...) = 0;
   virtual ~Interface() {} 
}
```

or

```
class Interface
{
public:
   virtual R1 f1(p11, p12 , ...) = 0;
   ...
   virtual Rn fn(pn1, pn2 , ...) = 0;
   virtual ~Interface() = 0; 
}
Interface::~Interface() {}
```

The first version is shorter to write
The second is attractive in that *all* functions of the interface are pure virtual

Is there any reason I should prefer one or the other method (or perhaps a third one)? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand, the purpose of making virtual function *pure virtual* is to force the derived classes to either provide implementation for it or choose the default implementation by *explicitly* writing `Base::f()` in the `Derived::f()`.

So if that is true, then what is the purpose of making virtual destructor `pure virtual`? Does it force the derived classes to provide implementation for `Base::~Base()`? Can the derived classes implement `Base::~Base()`? No.

So that means, the first version with `virtual` destructor seems enough for *almost* all purposes. After all, the most common purpose of virtual destructor is that the clients can correctly `delete` objects of the derived classes through pointers of type `Base*`.

However, if you make all functions in `Base` *virtual* only, **not** *pure* virtual, and provide implementations for them (actually you've to provide), and  at the same time you want to make `Base` *abstract type*, then having a *pure* virtual destructor in `Base` is the *only* solution:

```
class Base
{
public:
   virtual void f() {}; //not pure virtual
   virtual ~Base() = 0; //pure - makes Base abstract type!
};

Base::~Base() {} //yes, you have to do this as well.

Base *pBase = new Base(); // error - cannot create instance!
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

To me, the dtor is not part of the interface.  The fi() would have analogues in other languages, not the dtor.  Likewise, you could write pre- and post- conditions for the fi(), but not the dtor.  This makes it just a C++ wart, and the first technique is the most comfortable way of dealing with it.

Comment: Wart or not, C++ makes the destructor part of the interface. Whether it is virtual or not determines whether clients can validly `delete` an instance of the derived class through a pointer-to-base. Valid client actions == interface. Whether it's pure or not isn't part of the external interface, though, except as Nawaz says if it's the only pure function and hence makes the class abstract.

Comment: I agree, but the question is about virtual versus pure virtual, not virtual versus nonvirtual.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood you to mean that in general in C++, dtor is not part of the interface. I agree in this question, the difference between the options offered isn't part of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the derived class may choose whether or not to implement a destructor.
In the second case, the pure virtual destructor must be overridden, so the derived class is forced to implement a destructor.

Unless you have some reason why you want to force this, I would go with the first case.

Comment: Wrong. The second case doesn't force destructor to be overridden: http://ideone.com/aw3kV . Also, this sentence *"so the base class is forced to implement a destructor"* doesn't make sense to me. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @Nawaz - Sorry, bad typo.  I meant "derived", not "base".  It is now fixed.  Must stop writing code at 5:00am.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found a link and so thought I would mention it as an answer:

[Are inline virtual functions really a non-sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733737/are-inline-virtual-functions-really-a-non-sense/734543#734543)

> I've seen compilers that don't emit
>   any v-table if no non-inline function
>   at all exists (and defined in one
>   implementation file instead of a
>   header then). They would throw errors
>   like missing vtable-for-class-A or
>   something similar, and you would be
>   confused as hell, as i was.
>
> Indeed, that's not conformant with the
>   Standard, but it happens so consider
>   putting at least one virtual function
>   not in the header (if only the virtual
>   destructor), so that the compiler
>   could emit a vtable for the class at
>   that place. I know it happens with
>   some versions of gcc.
>   ([Johannes Schaub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb))

Its slightly different from your second case (suggests actually taking the function out of the header file altogether so as not to fall victim to gcc problem) but I thought I would mention it.  Quirks of gcc can occasionally bite.