# Why a member function being virtual affects the compiled code of a TU where no virtual dispatch is actually required?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, dynamic-dispatch, virtual-table

In a TU like this

```cpp
#include "Foo.hpp"
int main() {
    // stuff
    Foo* foo{new Foo{}};
    foo->foo();
    // stuff
}
```

where `Foo.hpp` contains

```cpp
#pragma once
struct Foo {
    virtual void foo(); // implmented somewhere
};
```

no call to anything other than `Foo::foo` can happen, right? `foo` is `virtual` and nor it nor the class are `final`, so yes, in *another* TU there could be objects of derived classes that `override` `foo`, and so on, but... as far as this TU is concerned I think it's pretty clear that `foo->foo()` calls `Foo::foo()`. I don't see how it could be otherwise.

Then why is the generated assembly like this?

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        mov     edi, 8
        call    operator new(unsigned long)@PLT
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rip + vtable for Foo@GOTPCREL]
        add     rcx, 16
        mov     qword ptr [rax], rcx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    Foo::foo()@PLT
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

I don't really understad it in detail, but I clearly read `vtable`. Why is it even there?

I'd have expected the assembly *of the TU above* to be the same as the one I get if I remove the `virtual` keyword:

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        mov     edi, 1
        call    operator new(unsigned long)@PLT
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    Foo::foo()@PLT
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

([Here's the example on CE](https://godbolt.org/z/TYevxndEe).)

From [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432062/5825294) I read that

> ```cpp
> A* a = new B;
> a->func();
> ```
>
> In this case the compiler can determine that `a` points to a `B` object and, thus, call the correct version of `func()` without dynamic dispatch. […] Of course, whether compilers do the corresponding analysis depends on its respective implementation.

Is the answer simply that Clang does not make the analysis that would allow to deduce that no runtime dispatch is needed?

Or am I missing something? Maybe I'm simply totally misunderstanding the assembly?

Comment: @273K, I've clarified that the class is defined in a header. That's just to say that I understand that virtual calls can be going on in other translation units linked to this one (maybe the `// stuff` part does make use of derived objects via pointers to base class).

Comment: `foo()` hos no body, the real bindings left till the linkage state. Add a body: https://godbolt.org/z/eosx6nG3M

Comment: *Clang does not make the analysis* This is not true. As you can see, it calls `Foo::foo()` directly. The dereferenced vtable is not used. It would be another question, why clang does not user dereferenced vtable result.

Comment: Reference to `vtable` is vtable pointer initialization for `*foo`.

Comment: @273K _This is not true_, indeed there's a _?_, so I'm just asking; _the real bindings left till the linkage state_, ok, but why should that affect the answer to my question, I don't get it?

Comment: @273K, defining `foo()` in that TU trivializes the whole compilation. The compiler is working out it can while everything away :/

Comment: Even if `foo()` is called directly, you still need a vtable pointer set up for the object on which that virtual function is called. What if inside `foo()` you do `typeid(*this)`?

Comment: An indirect call would look like a load from the object (to get the vptr) followed by something like `call qword ptr [rcx]`

Comment: In a classic "compile then link" toolchain, the *compiler* CANNOT know, due to the separate compilation model of C++ (when compiling one source file (.cc), it can't see contents of another) the compiler cannot assume there isn't a third source file that will derive a class from `Foo`, do something like `Foo *thing = new Derived_from_Foo; thing->foo();`.     Most basic linkers don't perform extensive (or any!) optimisation to remove unused code.

Answer (score 5):

The call to `foo` in the assembly that you are showing has been resolved to a direct call to `Foo::foo`.

The reference to the vtable is necessary because a pointer to it needs to be stored in the `Foo` object. The implementation of `Foo::foo` might rely on it, e.g. by using a `dynamic_cast`, `typeid`, or even just calling `foo` recursively, on `this`.

Comment: Indeed. And unsurprisingly, when `foo` is defined inline as empty, `main` is optimized away to `return 0;`.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
mov     rcx, qword ptr [rip + vtable for Foo@GOTPCREL]
```

initialises the vtable pointer.

The vtable mechanism is not used to call `Foo::foo`, however each object that has a vtable needs to have its vtable pointer initialised. If you don't initialise the vtable pointer of the `Foo` object,  `Foo::foo()` may break (for example, it can try and `dynamic_cast` `this`).

If you give `Foo::foo` an inlinable body, the compiler may (or may not) optimise away the entire `Foo` object, depending on what exactly is in the body. However it is unlikely that the compiler will allow an object with uninitialised vtable pointer to exist. It is just too much trouble and not worth the effort to handle this fringe case.