# the behavior of inline in gcc: inline of virtual function and especially destructor in my case

Tags: c++, gcc

The tricky part here is the define of BUILD_DEBUG_CLASS_MEMBER
in TestCompiler.cpp, I know I can just simply don't define it to solve the bug (please see the assertion in runtime result below)

My questions are:
**1.** why, in my case, virtual inline function is being inlined in TestCompiler.obj file
EVEN IF I don't call delete or whatever class methods of TriShape/Shape.
**2.** why in runtime, the inlined version from TestCompiler.o is called
but not the other version in Class.o.  (Not only the rumtime result below but also gdb shows it.)

Anyway, here I am just trying to study why gcc does the way it does now.
For example, it makes the .obj very big but it may help to inline as much as it
wants…!?  I am just guessing and I don't understand exactly.
( Since my bug (my stupid define) is obvious, so I prefer not to say it
is gcc's bug. ;) )

BTW, the compiler I have tested is gcc 4.4.7 and also VS2013. **ONLY**
the former cause assertion.
And, the original code base is in a library which is not mine and
so I cannot easily change the *Shape* files.
(ClassA is kind of factory and the Shape classes are the core of a library.)

Thank you very much for being patient and I am looking forward to your comments/answers.

---

## My program (sorry, a bit extra testing code is remained... ;) )

(ClassA is kind of factory and the Shape classes are the core originated from a library.)

```
//================================================================//
// TestCompiler.cpp
//

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "TestA.h"


#define BUILD_DEBUG_CLASS_MEMBER    // :)
#include "TriShape.h"           // include it just for testing compiler/linker in our case 


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("TC: main start \n");

    //TestA::gTestAFunc();
    gTestAFunc();

    // calls to TriShape::testVFunc, etc
    //...

    printf("TC: main finish \n");
    return 0;
}

//================================================================//
//TestA

#pragma once

extern void gTestAFunc();

//================================================================//
//TestA.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "ClassA.h"

void gTestAFunc()
{
    ClassA* pA = new ClassA();
    pA->createS();
    pA->removeS();
    delete pA;
}
//================================================================//
//ClassA.h

#pragma once

#include "Shape.h"


class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA()
        : m_pShape(NULL)
    {
    }

    void createS();

    void removeS();

    Shape* m_pShape;
};
//================================================================//
//ClassA.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "ClassA.h"

//#define BUILD_DEBUG_CLASS_MEMBER  // don't define it :)
#include "TriShape.h"


void ClassA::createS()
{
    m_pShape = new TriShape;
}

void ClassA::removeS()
{
    delete m_pShape;
    m_pShape = NULL;
}

//================================================================//
//Shape.h

#pragma once

class Shape //:: MemoryObject
{
public:
    Shape()
        : m_ptr(NULL)
    {
        printf("Shape ctor: this:%p  size:%d \n", this, sizeof(*this));
    }

    //TODO: inline it! :P
    virtual ~Shape()
    {
        //m_ptr
        printf("Shape dtor: this:%p  size:%d \n", this, sizeof(*this));
    }

    inline virtual int testVFunc()
    {
        return -1;
    }

    Shape* m_ptr;
};


//test ONLY:
//#include "TriShape.h"

//================================================================//
//TriShape.h

#pragma once

#include <assert.h>
#include "Shape.h"

#define FIX_NUM 0xABCD


class MyList
{
public:
    MyList()
        : m_dummy(FIX_NUM)
    {

    }

    //TODO: inline it! :P
    virtual ~MyList()
    {
        printf("List dtor: this:%p  size:%d  dummy:0x%x \n", this, sizeof(*this), m_dummy);
        assert(m_dummy==FIX_NUM);
//#pragma message( "List dtor here" )
    }

    int m_dummy;
};

class TriShape : public Shape
{
public:
    TriShape()
        //: m_debugMember()
    {
        printf("TriShape ctor: this:%p  size:%d \n", this, sizeof(*this));
    }


#if 1
    //caseT1
    virtual ~TriShape();
#else
    //caseT2
    virtual ~TriShape()
    {
        printf("TriShape dtor IN class: this:%p  size:%d \n", this, sizeof(*this));
#pragma message( "TriShape dtor here IN class" )
    }
#endif

    virtual int testVFunc();

#ifdef BUILD_DEBUG_CLASS_MEMBER
    MyList m_debugMember;
#endif
};


// inline dtor
#if 1
inline TriShape::~TriShape()
{
    printf("TriShape dtor AFTER class: this:%p  size:%d \n", this, sizeof(*this));

#pragma message( "TriShape dtor here AFTER class" )
#ifdef BUILD_DEBUG_CLASS_MEMBER
    #pragma message("\tit is defined: BUILD_DEBUG_CLASS_MEMBER")
#endif
}
#endif

// inline virutal func
inline int TriShape::testVFunc()
{
    printf("TriShape testVFunc AFTER class: this:%p  size:%d \n", this, sizeof(*this));
#pragma message( "TriShape testVFunc here AFTER class" )
#ifdef BUILD_DEBUG_CLASS_MEMBER
    #pragma message("\tit is defined: BUILD_DEBUG_CLASS_MEMBER")
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

## output during runtime

```
$ ./inlineTest
TC: main start
Shape ctor: this:0x995b018 size:8
TriShape ctor: this:0x995b018 size:8
TriShape dtor AFTER class: this:0x995b018 size:16
List dtor: this:0x995b020 size:8 dummy:0x20fe1
inlineTest: TriShape.h:22: virtual MyList::~MyList(): Assertion
`m_dummy==0xABCD' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

## read-able object code generated by -S to show that it is inlined in BOTH .asm

```
In TestCompiler.asm:
The destructor is inlned up this section
.section .text._ZN8TriShapeD1Ev,"axG",@progbits,_ZN8TriShapeD1Ev,comdat
(...)
call _ZN6MyListD1Ev
(...)
call _ZN5ShapeD2Ev

In ClassA.asm:
The destructor is inlned up this section
.section .text._ZN8TriShapeD1Ev,"axG",@progbits,_ZN8TriShapeD1Ev,comdat
(...)
call _ZN5ShapeD2Ev
```

## in the map file generated by linker (result of grep around dtor of TriShape)

```
.text._ZN8TriShapeD1Ev
0x0000000000000000 0x0 ClassA.o
.text._ZN8TriShapeD0Ev
0x0000000000000000 0x0 ClassA.o        //oops, ALL ZEROS means something??
(...)
.rel.text._ZN8TriShapeD1Ev
0x0000000000000000 0x0 /usr/lib/../lib/crt1.o
.rel.text._ZN8TriShapeD0Ev
0x0000000000000000 0x0 /usr/lib/../lib/crt1.o
(...)
.text._ZN8TriShapeD1Ev
0x0000000008048a80 0xb9 TestCompiler.o
0x0000000008048a80 _ZN8TriShapeD1Ev
*fill* 0x0000000008048b39 0x1 90909090
.text._ZN8TriShapeD0Ev
0x0000000008048b3a 0xb9 TestCompiler.o
0x0000000008048b3a _ZN8TriShapeD0Ev
*fill* 0x0000000008048bf3 0x1 90909090
```

Comment: I don't want to make my post too long and so, at the moment, I haven't talked about testVFunc().  Please feel free to skip it.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733737/are-inline-virtual-functions-really-a-non-sense

Comment: Thanks for your respond.  Actually I have read that post and could not find what I want - why gcc inlines in TestCompiler.obj and than picks it during link/runtime.

Again, TestCompiler.cpp doesn't even call any functions of TriShape/Shape.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are violating the one definition rule for `TriShape` so trying to guess why the compiler did something particular isn't likely to yield useful information. The compiler is allowed to assume that the class and functions will be identical in all sources files, so it may pick one and execute that code in all places.

Comment: As I have stated in the report above, I am trying to learn the internals of gcc but not how to avoid the bug here. Why gcc does inline the destructor in every cpp which includes TriShape? Thank you