# C++ error C2511: overloaded member function not found in 'Sprite'

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have a base class called `Renderable2D`:

```
class Renderer;

class Renderable2D
{
protected:
    vec3f m_Position;
    vec2f m_Size;
    unsigned int m_Color;

protected:
    Renderable2D() { }

    Renderable2D(vec3f position, vec2f size)
        : m_Position(position), m_Size(size), m_Color(0xffffffff)
    {
    }

public:
    virtual ~Renderable2D()
    { }

    virtual void Submit(Renderer * renderer) const;

    inline const vec3f& GetPosition() const { return m_Position; }
    inline const vec2f& GetSize() const { return m_Size; }
    inline unsigned int GetColor() const { return m_Color; }
};
```

The only thing I had to define in the cpp file was the `Submit` method to avoid circular inclusion:

```
#include "Renderable2D.h"
#include "../renderers/Renderer2D.h"
inline void Renderable2D::Submit(Renderer * renderer) const
{
    renderer->Submit(*this);
}
```

Then I derived a class from `Renderable2D` called `Sprite`:

```
#include "Renderable2D.h"

class Sprite : public Renderable2D
{
protected:
    GLuint m_TextureID;

public:
    Sprite(const vec2f& position, const vec2f& size, const Texture2D * texture);

    void Submit(Renderer * renderer) const override;

    inline const GLuint GetTextureID() const { return m_TextureID; }
};
```

And in the cpp file I just define the constructor and the overridden `Submit` method:

```
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "../renderers/Renderer2D.h"

Sprite::Sprite(const vec2f& position, const vec2f& size, const Texture2D * texture)
    : Renderable2D(vec3f(position.x, position.y, 0), size)
{
    m_TextureID = texture->GetTextureID();
}

inline void Sprite::Submit(Renderer * renderer) const
{  // ERROR HERE
    renderer->Submit(*this);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get error C2511, overloaded member function not found in 'Sprite'. I don't understand why. Is the signature wrong?

Edit: Here's the renderer class which is just a base class for all the renderers

```
class Renderable2D;
class Rectangle2D;
class Label;
class Sprite;

class Renderer2D
{
protected:
    std::vector<Maths::mat4f> m_TransformationStack;
    const Maths::mat4f * m_TransformationBack;

protected:
    Renderer2D()
    {
        m_TransformationStack.push_back(Maths::mat4f::identity());
        m_TransformationBack = &m_TransformationStack.back();
    }

public:
    inline void Push(const Maths::mat4f& matrix)
    {
        m_TransformationStack.push_back(matrix * m_TransformationStack.back());
        m_TransformationBack = &matrix;
    }

    inline void PushOverride(const Maths::mat4f& matrix)
    {
        m_TransformationStack.push_back(matrix);
        m_TransformationBack = &matrix;
    }

    void Pop()
    {
        if (m_TransformationStack.size() > 1)
            m_TransformationStack.pop_back();
        else
            Logging::Logger::Log(Logging::LogERROR, "Can't pop the first entry of the transformation stack!");

        m_TransformationBack = &m_TransformationStack.back();
    }

    virtual void Begin() {}
    virtual void End() {}

    virtual void Submit(const Renderable2D& renderable) = 0;
    virtual void Submit(const Label& label) = 0;
    virtual void Submit(const Rectangle2D& rect) = 0;
    virtual void Submit(const Sprite& spr) = 0;

    virtual void Flush() = 0;
};
```

And here's the header of the only Renderer that extends this class:

```
#include "Renderer2D.h"

class Batch2DRenderer : public Renderer2D
{
private:
    GLuint m_VAO;
    IndexBuffer * m_IBO;
    GLsizei m_IndexCount;
    GLuint m_VBO;
    VertexData * m_Buffer;
    std::vector<GLuint> m_TextureSlots;

public:
    Batch2DRenderer();
    ~Batch2DRenderer();

    void Begin() override;
    void End() override;

    void Submit(const Renderable2D& renderable) override;
    void Submit(const Label& label) override;
    void Submit(const Rectangle2D& rect) override;
    void Submit(const Sprite& spr) override;

    void Flush() override;

private:
    void init();
    float SubmitTexture(GLuint textureID);
};
```

The implementation file is really big, but I can provide that too if required. I guess the error is very misleading because there's something else here I guess.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my post. I guess Visual Studio went crazy because of some circular dependiency...

Comment: Did it work? because for me I was first facing a linking error, but after removing the word inline it worked. I didn't face the error that you were facing though

Comment: This code worked perfectly before I had subclasses of Renderable2D, and overloaded Submit() method for Renderer and Batch2DRenderer.

Comment: Well I could even link the repository if someone's generous enough to check it out (it's a Visual Studio project)

Comment: Try stripping the project of all the code unrelated to the function (`Submit`) giving the error and then see if the error persists. Since this started after some code movement, it code be a missing or stray bracket or semi-colon of some sort.

Comment: I'll rollback to the part it worked, open a branch and redo the stuff then :D.

Answer (score 0):

May be this problem cause using inline funtions. Read this [inline virtual functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733737/are-inline-virtual-functions-really-a-non-sense) it can help you.