# Can we make virtual function inline

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-optimization, virtual-functions

I have an abstract class *AbstractBufferQueue* and *BufferQueueAverage* is the class which is being used in the code always.

```
class AbstractBufferQueue 
{
    virtual void addSample(int s) = 0;
    virtual void removeSample(int s) = 0;

    void enqueue(int val) 
    {
        ...
        addSample(val);
    }
}

class BufferQueueAverage : public AbstractBufferQueue
{
    int n;
    double mean;

    void addSample(int s) { ++n; mean += (s - mean) / n; }
    void removeSample(int s) { ... }
    double getAverage() const { return mean; }
}
```

This question is from the compilers optimizations perspective.I want to know if we can make the virtual functions of the class *AbstractBufferQueueAverage* as inline.

Comment: The accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733737/are-inline-virtual-functions-really-a-non-sense seems to answer this well.

Comment: From the compiler writer's perspective, sure you can. Your compiler just wouldn't be a conforming implementation of the C++ language.